# Space complexity of this Inorder traversal in Binary Tree

Tags: python, binary-tree, tree-traversal, space-complexity

Below is the function for InOrder Traversal for a binary tree using Iteration. I want the space complexity to be constant.

The output is a list with N elements(N will be the number of nodes in the binary tree).
But since the size of the list will depend on the nodes, here the space cant be considered constant, right?

If instead of getting the list, I print the nodes when they are supposed to be appended in the list(if the list existed) will that make the space complexity O(1)?

What do I do to make the space constant in this?

```
def inorder_traversal(tree,callback = []):

  previousNode = None
  currentNode = tree


  while currentNode is not None:

    #if it is the root node  or node with left child
    if previousNode is None or previousNode == currentNode.parent:
      if currentNode.left is not None:  #cant just add this we need to traverse the left subtree

        nextNode = currentNode.left
        
      else: #currentNode's left child is None so we can add the currentNode and then go to its right child if right child present or we go up

        callback.append(currentNode.value)

        nextNode = currentNode.right if currentNode.right is not None else currentNode.parent


    elif previousNode == currentNode.left:  #we have checked the left subtree of the left child so we add the left child

      callback.append(currentNode.value)

      nextNode = currentNode.right if currentNode.right is not None else currentNode.parent

    else:
      nextNode = currentNode.parent


    previousNode = currentNode
    currentNode = nextNode 


  return callback
```

Comment: Looks like O(n) space complexity. Variable `callback` grows according to the size of the tree.

Comment: Recursive solution can keep space complexity constant: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

Comment: @pavel  We have to do it using iteration.